# Java Spring Scheduler Lock

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I have been trying to send notifications to my customers once. I'm using kubernetes and I create multiple spring boot applications because I have 2 replicas. This is all fine but when the scheduler runs, each one of them can send notifications. I have looked a little bit at quartz but the config seems to be a little complicated. Is there an easy way to do so?

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "300000")
public void sendFlowerNotification() {
  //Code
}
```

Comment: What database technology do you use?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: Perfect, my answer should support PostgreSQL

Comment: some info and tutorials related to quartz, I am sure this will help, give it a try: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule, http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html, http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html

Comment: If there are multiple application instances and you want your task to be run/scheduled by any one of the instances, then @Schedule is not an option, so here you need an scheduler which will have support for distributed system like quartz(using persisted scheduling and not in-memory).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use [dlock](https://github.com/yusufaytas/dlock) to execute a scheduled task only once over multiple nodes. You can simply do something like below.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "300000")
@TryLock(name = "flowerNotification", owner = POD_NAME, lockFor = THREE_MINUTES)
public void sendFlowerNotifications() {
  List<Notification> notifications = notificationService.getNotifications();
  for(Notification notification: notifications){
    sendNotification(notification);
  }
}
```

You can send the POD_NAME to spring as an environment variable. dlock would automatically handle it.

```
 env:
 - name: POD_NAME
   valueFrom:
     fieldRef:
       fieldPath: metadata.name
```

See the [article](https://dzone.com/articles/simple-mutual-exclusion) about using it.

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you very much for POD_NAME env config. I would have been losing a ton of time to figure out how to pass the pod name.